# psycopg2 error syntax error at or near None value

Tags: python, syntax, psycopg2

i have created this list and i am trying to retrieve some data from SQL with the following formula:

```
 list_upi= upi.tolist()
 json_string=json.dumps(list_upi)
 crr = sstn.query_db('aurora', f"""select "Carbon" from api.match_sec_str_array('{list_upi}')""")
 execute()
```

The list looks like this:

```
 0        1035711463.0
 1        1007978477.0
 2        1250122485.0
 3        1008200741.0
 4        2000828698.0
```

But for some reason some data can't be fined and i got this error

```
 syntax error at or near "None"
 LINE 1: ...879.0, 1008759844.0, 1008144844.0, 1008156925.0, 'None', 100...
```

Is there a way i can change the none values to null or anything like that so the code doesn't stop when data will not be found. Thanks in advance!
PS: i have tried this with data that exists in the database, and it does work, it's only this time when it doesn't.

Comment: The syntax error is from SQL, not Python. `list_upi` apparently has the value `None`, which results in a malformed SQL query. Do *not* use string formatting operation to generate SQL; use whatever support for parameterized queries your library provides. In addition, make sure your query makes sense if `upi.tolist()` returns `None`, or take the appropriate action in lieu of making the query if not.

Comment: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: Also psycopg2 has built-in [JSON](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json) support.